# Fix the 'Bad request' when receiving ajax data

Tags: python, flask

Briefly, I am sending data from a SelectField (WTFORMS) using Ajax to update other SelectField choices dynamically.

i have tried to send data as default or json, in both cases unsuccessfully.

here is the final code i tried:

in the jinja2 template:

```
[...]
<th width="20%">{{ studsubreg.sub }}</th>
[...]
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select#studsubreg-sub").change(function() {



            var subid = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            {#var subid=$(this).val();#}

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 'sid': subid},
                url: "{{ url_for('getcourse') }}",
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                success: function(response) {
                }
            });


    });
});


</script>
```

in Flask: (just to test if the output is working)

```py
@app.route('/getcourse', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def getcourse():
    subid = request.json['sid']
    print(subid)
```

i always get error 400  Bad request
i just want to get the subid value so i can return the results to populate the other SelectField.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `request.args.get('sid')`.

You are just getting one of the argument using Ajax.

Also remove `contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'`.